# Makefile: make multiple c files to multiple binaries

Tags: c, makefile

I have a bunch of C files in a directory (each file named such that it starts with the characters `program`, e.g. `program1.c`, `program2.c`, `program3.c`) and I intend for each of these C files to compile into its respective binary (`program1`, `program2`, `program3`).

How would I write a `Makefile` to achieve this so I can simply issue `make` to create multiple binaries?  (**Using a loop** instead of manually stating a make statement for each c source file)

Here's my attempt:-

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g 
SRCS=$(wildcard program*.c)

all:
    for F in *.c; do \
    F=$${$$F.%c}; make $$F; done

clean:
    rm -f program1
    rm -f program2
    rm -f program3
```

which gives me a `bad subsitution` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PROGS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    /bin/rm $(PROGS)
```

shall do it.